# 127.0.0.1/asd does'not work on ubuntu environment

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu, webserver

I was working on microsoft environment, but now I moved my website to ubuntu, the problem is, when I try to write a link like this, 127.0.0.1/asd, I get not found error, the thing that makes me crazy is, that URL sometimes work sometimes does not work and It was working great on windows environment, this is the error I get,

```
Not Found The requested URL /asd was not found on this server.
```

this is my .htaccess,

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([//a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ tab.php?tab_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be your rewrite rule - "//" should be "\/" - what does your apache conf file look like, does it have .htaccess enabled for that directory?